# Meta Refresh with #-anchor going into loop

Tags: html, firefox, opera

The following construct,

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=#scroll" />
```

when accessed from `http://localhost/`, redirects all browsers to `http://localhost/#scroll`, and no further redirecting occurs as expected.

However, when the very same construct is used from the target url, `http://localhost/#scroll`, firefox and opera keep refreshing the page every 3 seconds, making http requests to the server, regardless of the fact that the url for redirect has already been reached.

Is there any explanation and/or fix for this?

NB for possible solutions: JavaScript is unavailable in this specific situation.

Comment: I'm curious — why isn't Javascript an option here?  You seem to have the ability to alter the HTML, so an inline script would seem to be a low-impact solution.

Comment: Because the very reason behind using this trick is displaying a message for a javascript-disabled browser. And "noscript" tag fails in Opera.

Comment: For one thing, I don't want the user to worry about the annoying message on slow links, at the same time I want to make a good guess about how much time it takes for a page to load, and meta-refresh to display a message if javascript didn't take over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you're interested, what Firefox is doing is that it normally treats meta refresh as a forced new document load. But in the case where the URI changes within 15 seconds, it changes it to a replace. And then later on this lets the anchor scroll check succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think meta refresh was designed to jump to anchors.

If you can't use JavaScript, you can't automate it.

Comment: @etranger What I mean, it may *jump just fine*, but meta refresh probably wasn't intended to do this, so you are experiencing side effects. Without using JavaScript, you can't add any conditions or similar to prevent this problem I believe.

Comment: not conventionally, I agree. Safari and Chrome appear to be smarter, and don't network-refresh pages that only differ in a #-anchor. Still, there must be some logic in browser making a decision about refreshing, and understanding it could prove useful in making a workaround. Hence my asking.